# What is the vertex of $y=-\left|x+1\right|+5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble finding the vertex of $y=-\left|x+1\right|+5$. Is it even possible, this doesn't seem to be a quadratic function.

Comment: It's not a quadratic. I'm not familiar with the term "vertex" in terms of these functions with absolute values but I assume it be the point where the function has a min/max and "switches direction".  i.e. when the absolute value is zero.  x = -1 and y = 5.  (not sure how to formally define such.

Comment: D'oh.  "vertex" refers to an angle vertex.  i.e. the graph forms an angle.  What is the vertex.

Comment: Either of these definitions of "vertex" apply here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28geometry%29, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28curve%29

Answer (score 4):

The graph of $y=|x|$ has an absolute minimum at the point $(0,0)$.  The graph of the function you mention would be the graph of the function $y=|x|$ reflected about the x-axis, shifted left 1 unit, and then shifted up 5 units.  So the point $(0,0)$ on $y=|x|$ would correspond to the point $(-1,5)$ on the graph of $y=-|x+1|+5$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

Since $x+1\ge 0$ for $x \ge -1$ your equation becomes:
$$
y=\begin{cases}
(x+1)+5=x+6 \quad \mbox{for} \quad x< -1\\
-(x+1)+5=-x+4\quad \mbox{for} \quad x\ge -1\\
\end{cases}
$$
so it is a straight line with positive slope for $x<-1$ and a straight line with negative slope for $x\ge -1$ and in $x=-1$ the value of the function is $y=5$.

[image]